# How Android Photo Framing apps work

Tags: android

So I've got a weird one here. having googled and tried different tutorials on photo framing apps, I have come up really short of an idea of how to even begin. So far, my app is almost ready, save for the part where the user takes a picture and this picture is automatically framed and labeled with with text stored in the database. Any ideas on how these frames can be created and generally how to fix said text on specific parts of the picture? So far, my only thought has been to create a frame on Photoshop, and a blank, transparent area in the center where the picture would fit. But that's just how far I've gone. Thanks, in anticipation of your reply

Answer (score 0):

Add a border:

```
result = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
Paint paint = new Paint();
canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
canvas.drawBitmap(mImage, 15, 15, paint);
```

Add text:

```
Canvas c = new Canvas(bmSelectedImage);
Paint fillPaint = new Paint();
fillPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);

int width = (int) fillPaint.measureText(mStringImageText);
int yPos = (int) ((c.getHeight() - (c.getHeight()/10)) - ((fillPaint.descent() + fillPaint.ascent()) / 2) - 10);
fillPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
fillPaint.setTextSize((c.getHeight() / 18));
fillPaint.setColor(Color.parseColor(mColorFill));
c.drawText(mStringImageText, (bmSelectedImage.getWidth() - width) / 2, yPos, fillPaint);
```